# jQuery prepend query in only prev div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to move .treamentCost within .treatmentDetails when the window is below < 400px

This works fine, my problem is i only want the .treatmentCost within the div directly above it (.test) to move within the below .treatmentDetails.

At the moment it finds every .treatmentCost and prepends in to .treatmentDetails

Please see the below js fiddle to see the issue. If you run the fiddle with the fiddle results window ABOVE the width of 400px you will see '£100' and '£200' are outside the grey .treatmentDetails div. When you drag the browser in and the results window is BELOW a width of 400px and run the fiddle again, you will see the .treatmentCosts prepend within .treatmentDetails.

I need only the '.treatmentCost' within the '.test' div directed a before the .treatmentDetails to prepend not ALL divs with the class of .treatmentCost as is happening at the moment.

So the successfull end result will be that '£100' will be within the first gry div and '£200' will be within the second grey div.

http://jsfiddle.net/fzMHq/1/

// CODE //

// JS //

```
<script>
if ($(window).width() < 400) {
    $(".treatmentDetails").prepend( $(".treatmentCost") );
}
</script>
```

// HTML //

```
<div id="accordion">

<div class="test dark">

<div class="treatmentLeft">
<p>Face Mapping Skin Analysis</p>
</div><!--treamentLeft close-->

<div class="treatmentLength">
<p>10 mins</p>
</div><!--treamentLength close-->

<div class="treatmentCost">
<p>£100</p>
</div><!--treamentCost close-->

</div><!--test close-->

<div class="treatmentDetails dark" style="background-color: #eee;">
<p>Our Face Mapping skin analysis will enable our therapist to diagnose your skin’s
concerns and recommend a home-care and treatment regimen to ensure your optimum skin
health. This is a professional consultation that will give your skin its healthiest
future.</p>
</div><!--treamentDetails close-->




<div class="test dark">

<div class="treatmentLeft">
<p>Face Mapping Skin Analysis</p>
</div><!--treamentLeft close-->

<div class="treatmentLength">
<p>10 mins</p>
</div><!--treamentLength close-->

<div class="treatmentCost">
<p>£200</p>
</div><!--treamentCost close-->

</div><!--test close-->

<div class="treatmentDetails dark" style="background-color: #eee;">
<p>Our Face Mapping skin analysis will enable our therapist to diagnose your skin’s 
concerns and recommend a home-care and treatment regimen to ensure your optimum skin
health. This is a professional consultation that will give your skin its healthiest
future.</p>
</div><!--treamentDetails close-->

</div><!--ACCORDION close-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fzMHq/3/)

```
if ($(window).width() < 400) {
    $(".treatmentDetails").each(function () {
        $(this).prepend($(this).prev(".test").find('.treatmentCost'));
    });
}
```

you can use `.children('.treatmentCost'));` instead of `.find('.treatmentCost'));`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/fzMHq/2/)

if you want to code in `$(window).resize()`

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 400) {
        $(".treatmentDetails").each(function(){
            $(this).prepend($(this).prev(".test").find('.treatmentCost'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This endlessly prepends the cost as you dynamically resize. OP requested that it simply prepend the corresponding cost per each `treatmentDetails`.

Comment: @kunalbhat i just gave him option and also i have given the code he wanted below

Comment: Brilliant thanks :-) I notice the .treatmentCost now prepends into the div without a reload of the page or in this case are re 'run' of the fiddle. Is there a way to get it to revert back once the user drags the browser back out above 400px with a browser refresh. Thanks for your help this had been a headache all day!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).width() < 400) {
    $(".treatmentDetails").each(function() {
        $(this).prepend($(this).prev(".test").find(".treatmentCost"));
    });
}
```

Comment: just noticed that the previous poster also edited his answer to contain this exact code too.

Comment: i posted this code 5 min before you.--->You can check http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18340915/revisions version 2 and it's demo also

Comment: relax, I'm not saying you copied me...  I was just noticing that when I finished typing the comment and the page reloaded, there was an identical answer right above mine.

Comment: Thanks for this, if it was up to me i would 'green tick' all answers but unfortunately its only letting me tick once :-) thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).width() < 400) {
   for(var i=0 ; i<$(".treatmentDetails").length; i++) 
    $(".treatmentDetails").eq(i).prepend( $(".treatmentCost").eq(i) );
}
```

Try this . Hope this works as you asked!

http://jsfiddle.net/fzMHq/4/

Comment: how about this approach?

Comment: I have no idea what is going on in this script (my js knowledge is poor) But it seems to work perfectly as well! Thanks for your time

Comment: hi @jarrett owen can you accept this as correct answer and vote up?

Comment: Hi, it seems i can only give one solution the tick mark. And as Tushar was the first to solve the problem, and in jquery i have left the check mark there. Thanks for your solution though, it is a good alternative!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Tushar Gupta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18340915/1947286) if you would like the resize function to work in both directions:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/fzMHq/5/)**

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 400) {
        $(".treatmentDetails").each(function () {
            $(this).prepend($(this).prev(".test").find('.treatmentCost'));
        });
    } else {
        $(".test").each(function () {
            $(this).append($(this).next(".treatmentDetails").find('.treatmentCost'));
        });
    }
});
```